# Camel REST path params in headers - a security issue?

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I understand that inbound REST path parameters are getting automatically mapped to Camel headers. The problem I suspect that this mechanism might get exploited, overwriting Camel headers which might be required for routes to work (like the `Host` header for an outbound CXFRS endpoint, to name an example), or get conflicting with them at least.

Why doesn't Camel handle REST path parameters for the request somewhere completely separately of Camel headers which in many cases are absolutely required for correct Camel component behaviour? How can one avoid conflicts between the two using the same name, or in worst case avoid this becoming a security issue?

Comment: for the close voters - please get into details why you think this question is too broad. 

It asks how the path params mechanism wouldn't conflict with the outbound HTTP headers. How could this be more specific?

Comment: The onus is on you to provide examples of this. You are asking a question which  most of us have never encountered in production and without examples so it is very broad and I can understand the downvotes. Interesting question,  but you need to show more of what you are concerned about.

Comment: @Namphibian I'm not sure why you think this needs to be clarified or needs and example, I think it is very clear.  The fact that no one on the Camel team deems it necessary to even respond to (what I think) is a legitimate concern is troublesome, especially considering it's a security issue.  As usual, it seems that the best approach may be to avoid Camel altogether and go with something more standard and secure like Spring.  This is my suggestion after 2 years of Camel experience.

Comment: @java-addict301 I was asking for an example of how this might be a security concern. I have been using Camel successfully for over 9 years and have not run into an issue like this

Answer (score 0):

I am Assmuing your questions here as why should camel consider the http headers as camel header and forwards the request rest.

TO resolve this what you can do is, in Processor Create an exchange (1) with the existing Exhange(0 - orginal exchange) handle with Pattern INOUT.

and once you get the response you reuse the exchange (response exhcnage in OUT -3) and set back to Exchange(0).

```
    class customProcessor implements Processor {
    void process(Exchange ogx){

         Exchange exchange = ExchangeBuilder.anExchange(camelContext)
                                     .withPattern(ExchangePattern...)
                                     .withHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, HttpMethod.GET)
                                      .build();
             Exchange  responseExchange=producer.send("the end point to rest",exchange); 
//copying the exchange which has come as response from the rest to the body of //the OGX exchange.


ogx.getIn().setBody(responseExchange.getOut().getBody())


    }

    }
```